# Is it possible to set project's Output Path property from nuget powershell?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, nuget

I would like to set Visual Studio project property "Output Path" from nuget powershell console. How could it be done?

I have found [a blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2011/05/15/set-the-properties-on-your-visual-studio-project.aspx) describing how to set some project properties, but Output Path is not included.

Furthermore, the Output Path property depends on current build configuration (Debug/Release). How can be the Output Path set for any configuration (not active at the time)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to set `(Get-Project).ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.Properties.Item("OutputPath").Value` for example:

```
(Get-Project).ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.Properties.Item("OutputPath").Value = "bin\NewDebugPath"
```