# Is it possible to set OutputPath in powershell with build macro's?

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget, csproj

Related to this question: [Is it possible to set project's Output Path property from nuget powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312635/is-it-possible-to-set-projects-output-path-property-from-nuget-powershell)

How can I set the output path of a project to use macro's? Just as when you edit it in the csproj file.

```
(Get-Project).ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.Properties.Item("OutputPath").Value =
    "$(SolutionDir)bin"
```

This resolves in

```
<OutputPath>%24%28SolutionDir%29\bin</OutputPath>
```

But should have been

```
<OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\bin</OutputPath>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by changing the csproj via xml

```
function Set-OutputPathRaw( $projectObj, $outputPath )
{
<#

.SYNOPSIS
Set the output path directly in the csproj file

.PARAMETER projectObj
The project to set

.PARAMETER outputPath
The path to set in the output path. May use dollar-sign macros

#>
    $projectObj.Save() # save beforehand

    $csproj = [xml](Get-Content $projectObj.FullName)

    $nsmgr = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager -ArgumentList $csproj.NameTable
    $nsmgr.AddNamespace('a', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003')

    $outputpathnodes = $csproj.SelectNodes('/a:Project/a:PropertyGroup/a:OutputPath/text()',$nsmgr)

    foreach($outputnode in $outputpathnodes)
    {
        $outputnode.Value = $outputPath
    }

    $csproj.Save($projectObj.FullName)
}
```

Call this via:

```
Set-OutputPathRaw $project "`$(SolutionRoot)\bin\`$(Configuration)"
```